# Where to manage the transaction, Java or MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm developing the new software of my company from zero, so I was on a meeting with my team and we end up to talk about where we are going to put the transaction?, some of my team said that is better on MySQL and said that is more safe, others prefer to use Java for the transaction management because if we need to execute more than one stored procedure is easy to commit or rollback the transaction from java, Can someone share his experience of this topic?, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java transaction management will very often use database transactions in addition to any application level locking.  I recommend using some framework that has this all worked out already, such as [Spring transactions](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) or Java EE transactions.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with putting the transactions in MySQL? To use transactions in MySQL, you will still need to use the JDBC API to commit or rollback those transactions, so there is actually just one option(*) and that is to use Java/JDBC (which will then control the MySQL transaction). *: at least, the other option would be to try and circumvent the JDBC driver which would be brittle and could potential introduce bugs as it can bring the JDBC driver in an incorrect state.

Comment: What I mean is to use the transactions on storedprocedure